# remove the array strings in the given string?

Tags: java, str-replace

```
String fullname="Mr Vivek N Nandakumar Sr";
String [] strst={"Sr.", "sr.", "Jr.", "jr.","Jr ","jr ","Sr ","sr "," Jr"," jr"," Sr"," sr",",I",".I","I.","II","III"," IV","IV ",".IV",",IV", "V.","V ",".V",",V","VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X" ,"M.D","MBA","PhD","M.A","Mr.","Mr ","Mrs.","Miss","MISS","miss","MR ","MRS ","mr ","mrs "," mr"," mrs","Dr ","DR ","Dr.","DR.",")","("};
```

I just want to remove the this given array strings from the fullname..

I want a output be like ...."Vivek N Nandakumar"

Comment: providing a sample of your code and more information, you will get better answers to your question. I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of answers you receive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Java you are using, but in Java 8 i would use streams like so:

```
Arrays.stream(fullname.split(" ")).filter(namePart -> Arrays.stream(strst).noneMatch(str -> str.trim().equals(namePart))).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

for me the output came as you wanted.

***EDIT***

This would be the case for JAVA 7. Before that you have to implement your own search.

```
    String fullname="Mr Vivek N Nandakumar Sr";
    String [] strst={"Sr.", "sr.", "Jr.", "jr.","Jr ","jr ","Sr ","sr "," Jr"," jr"," Sr"," sr",",I",".I","I.","II","III"," IV","IV ",".IV",",IV", "V.","V ",".V",",V","VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X" ,"M.D","MBA","PhD","M.A","Mr.","Mr ","Mrs.","Miss","MISS","miss","MR ","MRS ","mr ","mrs "," mr"," mrs","Dr ","DR ","Dr.","DR.",")","("};
    Arrays.sort(strst);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String namePart :
            fullname.split(" ")) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(strst, namePart, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.trim().compareTo(o2.trim());
            }
        }) < 0 ) {
            sb.append(namePart).append(" ");
        }
    } 
    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Well, i think you can expand a bit this and make the loops yourself, but the logic is there :P Whenever i have time i can edit it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have constrain over space complexity, than try to split the main string using space(if space separated) in an array, and check every value with the given array if found remove that one from the main string array and at the end concatenate the main string array. I will say use set to store the second list, it will help you to increase the time performance. it will reduce the time from O(n^2) to O(n).